# How to make new Excel 2007 functions like SUMIFS work in Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

I using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for Java to set formulas in Excel cells. I'm using the following code to make the formulas appear as formulas rather than as Strings:

```
// "cell" object previously created or looked up
String StrFormula = "SUM(\"A1:A10\")";
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula(strFormula);
```

The `setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)` makes the trick for most formulas but not all. There are some functions (introduced in Excel 2007) like SUMIFS, COUNTIFS. IFERROR, AVERAGEIFS that cause the cell to contain a String. It is necessary to click+enter every such cell in Excel for the formula to get recognized. Is there any trick to make those functions work properly?

Comment: Are you triggering a [Formula Evaluation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) at the end of processing your file? And if not, does doing that help?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since this question was asked, but as I faced a similar problem recently, I'll try to answer it.

In our case we had to switch to `XSSF` document classes (instead of `HSSSF`) to support Excel2007 values.